# Compile opus-tools with opus 1.2.1

Tags: compiling, codecs, ogg-opus

I would like to compile opus-tools with libopus 1.2.1.

I got libopus 1.2.1 source code from here :
https://opus-codec.org/release/stable/2017/06/26/libopus-1_2_1.html

I extracted it, and then did :

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Everything went fine and now I have an "opus" folder in /usr/include and some "libopus.*" files in /usr/local/lib

Now I got opus-tools source code from here :
https://opus-codec.org/downloads/

I extracted it, and then did :
    ./configure
And I got this error message at the end :

```
checking for Opus... no
*** Could not run Opus test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means Opus was incorrectly installed
*** or that you have moved Opus since it was installed.
configure: error: 
    Opus is required to build this package!
    please see http://opus-codec.org/ for how to
    obtain a copy.
```

How come it doesn't find the libopus library I just built ?
How can I link to it ?

Thank you for your help !
Cheers

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention that I am on Lubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

## Installing packages from repositories

OPUS is packaged in Ubuntu (including 18.04 LTS). All you need is to search on [packages.ubuntu.com for `opus`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=opus).

And you will get the following packages:

> - Package `libopus-dev`
>     bionic (18.04LTS) (libdevel): Opus codec library development files
>     1.1.2-1ubuntu1: amd64
>     ...
> - Package `libopus0`
>     bionic (18.04LTS) (libs): Opus codec runtime library
>     1.1.2-1ubuntu1: amd64
>     ...
> - Package `opus-tools`
>     bionic (18.04LTS) (sound): Opus codec command line tools [universe]
>     0.1.10-1: amd64

So I suggest to install these packages from repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libopus-dev libopus0 opus-tools
```

## Manual compilation (bad idea)

Enable Source Code repository in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).

Install opus build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libopus0 opus-tools
```

Download and compile new opus (are you sure that 1.2.1 is better than 1.1.2-1ubuntu1?):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/opus/opus-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar -xf opus-1.2.1.tar.gz
cd opus-1.2.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Download and install opus-tools (exactly the same version as in repository):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/opus/opus-tools-0.1.10.tar.gz
tar -xf opus-tools-0.1.10.tar.gz
cd opus-tools-0.1.10/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Note: the `sudo make install` is bad idea too, consider to use `checkinstall` instead.

Comment: Thank you NOrbert ! The thing is, I want to try version 1.2.1 instead of version 1.1.2. Is it better ? I honestly don't have any idea, but I want to see if it fixes a problem I get with some files.

Comment: Then you can try  second part of the answer. It should end with success as I tested it on my clean 18.04 LTS VM.